# FDT adding unnecessary imports for core Flash/AIR classes.

Tags: flash, air, fdt

When working in an AIR project, FDT is importing flash.filesystem.File and other the other classes in that package when its not necessary to do so. Even w/ errors being shown in FDT, this still compiles and runs. The problem with these unnecessary imports is that FDT shows it as an error, when it is not, and when working w/ other devs w/ other IDES (FlashBuilder or Intellij), those IDEs remove those filesystem imports. So its a constant back-n-forth every time we commit to SVN.

I did a very quick check and this is the case for: flash.filesystem, flash.data, flash.concurrent, flash.desktop, flash.filters and flash.html.

Is there a way to correct this behavior in FDT?  I didn't see one, and filed a bug on http://bugs.powerflasher.com but I'm not sure how how active still is.

Comment: This does sound like a bug. Could you please switch the issue from improvement to bug. http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-2990

Comment: Alan - I don't see a way that I can switch that issue. but I did accidentally manage to clone the issue (oops).

Comment: The admin should convert the issue to a bug.